# JavaFX - How to center axis tick mark labels

Tags: javafx, charts, axis

Would like to set `text-alingment` to `center` for the x-axis tick label of a JavaFX chart.

I have a JavaFX NumberAxis X-axis with Dates, using multi-line text for the tick labels. Setting the tick label to "dd/MMM\YYYY" or "HH:mm\ndd/MMM" with `AxisX.setTickLabelFormatter(getTimeAxisString())`. User function getTimeAxisString() provides the formatted string for the tick label. By default this results in text aligned left, like shown in this picture:
[axis tick labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ukwZ.png)

Is there a JavaFx method to change the text-alingment here? Can I assign a CSS class to the tick label ?

Comment: hmm .. not sure what you mean, the alignment of the second line of the wrapped text? Would expect that to be supported on the label/text level, so css might work

Answer (score 5):

Astonishingly, styling the labels for the ticks is not directly supported. Plus all charts and collaborators take great care to *not* expose the nodes in their hierarchy in any api (not even internally). So looks like we need to rely on implementation details of Axis ..

- the class encapsulating the state of the label for a tick is TickMark
- it has a field of type String, named label: that's the string representation of the value, configurable by a converter value -> String
- it has a field of type Text, named textNode: that's the node added to the Axis and the node we want to style
- Text as such has no default style class, that is not accessible via `axis.lookup(style)`
- textNode has no default custom style that might have been set by its parent axis (that's in contrast to the axis label)

The basic task is to get access to the Text and then style it, either by directly configuring its properties or by setting a custom style class and configure it via css.

The basic solution path is to listen to the axis children and configure the properties of all nodes of type Text when added. The snippet below sets a custom style class.

```
xAxis.getChildrenUnmodifiable().addListener((ListChangeListener<Node>) c -> {
    while (c.next()) {
        if (c.wasAdded()) {
            for (Node mark : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                if (mark instanceof Text) {
                    mark.getStyleClass().add("axis-tick-mark-text-node");
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
});
```

Example styling:

```
.axis-tick-mark-text-node {
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
    -fx-fill: red;
}
```

Comment: Astonishingly indeed. I was surprised (+ frustrated) failing to get a hold of the tick label element. Your solution  should get a hold of it. Will try and get back to confirm it works. Thanks